# Add element after a set of elements only if it hasn't been added previously using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dhtml

I have some jQuery code that finds elements with the *shaded* CSS class and adds a div element after it. It is run in the document ready event handler.

```
$(".shaded").after("<div class='shader'></div>");
```

The shader class provides styling to make the above element look raised.

My problem is that we started using Ajax to populate content, so now I need to run the code above each time new content is retrieved using Ajax.

What I want to know is how I can detect if this dynamically added "shader" div has previously been added. I know I can find those next elements using this:

```
$(".shaded").next("div").hasClass("shader")
```

But how do I elegantly add the "shader" **only** to the elements that have not been shaded yet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".shaded + :not(.shader)").prev().after("<div class='shader'></div>");
```

works and [tested](http://jsfiddle.net/fU5uZ/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (untested though):

```
$(".shaded + :not('div.shader')").prev().after("<div class='shader'></div>");
```

It finds all divs with class `shaded` and filters out the ones that do not have a div with class `.shader` after them.

Thanks to @Joseph for pointing out the `.prev()`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should really solve this with CSS. But I can imagine situations where that is hard to do (*cough*IE6*cough*).

You could do it the nasty jQuery way and derive which elements already have a shader, like Mrchief's solution.
Or you take the responsible solution and keep a list of elements that have been shaded, and even better, a list of elements that still need to be shaded.

jQuery encourages you to 'abuse' your DOM for storing information about your model, while you really should just make a model and use jQuery based on the information in the model. This is exactly the reason why I'm no longer using jQuery for anything that doesn't involve very complex tasks (I still use it for animations and fancy plugins like *lightboxes*).

Comment: Yes, with CSS3, this can be accomplished using box-shadow, but I need wider support.
.shaded
{
    box-shadow: 0 0.3em 0.3em #999;
    margin-bottom: 1.3em;
}